# Dynamic filtering using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<Device>`. In the `Device` class there are 4 properties, namely `Name`, `OperatingSystem`, `Status` and `LastLoggedInUser`. I need to write a method:

```
IQueryable<Device> FilterDeviceList(
    List<Device> Devices,
    List<string> filter,
    string filterValue)
```

where `filter` will contain options for filtering `"name"`, `"os"` to indicate the fields to include in the search. If `"all"` is passed then all 4 fields need to be included.
`filtervalue` will contain the value to be filtered like `"windows"`, `"Calvin"`.

Can anyone suggest a method to achieve this?

Edit:

If I was not clear, I am doing the filtering somewhat like this, it is the commented part for which I need the code.

```
if(filter.contains(name))
{
//filter with name
}
if( filter.contains(both name and os)
{
// I only need the filter value to contain in name or OS (only needed in any one of the field,not necessary to be in both)

}`
```

Comment: you can always do this with if statements, but I do not know if it can be done with dynamic LINQ.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could build your query as follows:

```
private static IQueryable<Device> FilterDeviceList(List<Device> devices, Device device)
{
    var query = devices.AsQueryable();

    if (device.Name != null)
        query = query.Where(d => d.Name == device.Name);

    if (device.OS != null)
        query = query.Where(d => d.OS == device.OS);

    if (device.Status != null)
        query = query.Where(d => d.Status == device.Status);

    if (device.LastLoggedInUser != null)
        query = query.Where(d => d.LastLoggedInUser == device.LastLoggedInUser);

    return query;
}
```

Then you can call this function with a device object. I.e. if you want name to be included, just pass a device object with a name (leave other properties to their default value). If you want everything to be included, pass in a device object with everything filled in:

```
var r = FilterDeviceList(devices, new Device
            {
                Name = "yourFilterValue",
                OS = "yourFilterValue",
                LastLoggedInUser = "yourFilterValue",
                Status = "yourFilterValue"
            });
```

**Edit, filter on name property:**

```
var r = FilterDeviceList(devices, new Device
                {
                    Name = "yourFilterValue"
                });
```

**Edit 2, take a look at [predicatebuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)**

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Device>();

if(document.Name != null)
    predicate = predicate.Or(d => d.Name == document.Name);

if(document.OS != null)
    predicate = predicate.Or(d => d.OS == document.OS);

return devices.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I like it.

Comment: @dieter Thanks for the quick reply. I have edited, pls can u have a look, I need to acheive that

Comment: In my example you don't need a 'filter' list. If you want everything to be included, just pass in an object with all the properites filled in. If you want to filter just on the name, pass in an object were only the property name is filled in.

Comment: I tried you code, but what I am getting is
alldevices.where(firstcondition).where(second condition).
But What I need is
if(filters.contain(Name))
alldevices.where(name == value)
if(filters.contain(name,OS)
alldevices.where(name||os == value)

Comment: See updated answer, take a look at predicate builder

Comment: Spot On :-) That was 2 days of my work to a fruitful stage. Thanks Buddy

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Device> FilterDevices(IEnumerable<Device> devices, IEnumerable<Func<Device, string>> filters, string filterValue)
{
    foreach (var filter in filters)
    {
        devices = devices.Where(d => filter(d).Equals(filterValue));
    }

    return devices;
}
```

With:

```
public class Device
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OS { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var devices = new List<Device>
{
    new Device { OS = "Windows", Name = "Foo" },
    new Device { OS = "Mac", Name = "Bar" }
};

var filters = new List<Func<Device, string>>
{
    d => d.OS
};

var result = FilterDevices(devices, filters, "Windows");
```

This is just a rough idea - convert for your solution as needed!

Answer (score 0):

You have basically 2 options:

1. Use System.Linq.Expression API to build your LINQ predicates (lots of work but a nice reusable solution if done right). You'll still need to map filter names and properties on something (same name for example)
2. Hardcode the mapping between filter names and your `Func<TObject, TFilterValue, bool>` predicates. You can do that in a static dictionary (or plain old switch). Just make sure you create a closure over your predicates and bind your filter values. The Where call expects a `Func<T, bool>`

Answer (score 0):

```
private IQueryable<Device> FilterCentraStageDeviceList(List<Device> centraStageDevices, string filter, string filterValue)
    {
        IQueryable<Device> alldevices = centraStageDevices.AsQueryable<Device>();
        IQueryable<Device> query = new List<Device>().AsQueryable();

        if (filter == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterValue))
        {
            return alldevices;
        }

        filterValue = filterValue.ToLower();          
        var filterLower = filter.ToLower();

        if (filterLower.Contains("all") || (filterLower.Contains("hostname") && filterLower.Contains("operatingsystem") && filterLower.Contains("status") && filterLower.Contains("lastloggedinuser")))
        {
            return alldevices.Where(x => checkNull(x.Name).Contains(filterValue) || checkNull(x.OperatingSystem).Contains(filterValue) || checkNull(x.LastUser).Contains(filterValue));               
        }

        if (filterLower.Contains("hostname"))
        {
            query = alldevices.Where(x => checkNull(x.Name).Contains(filterValue));
        }

        if (filterLower.Contains("operatingsystem"))
        {
            query = alldevices.Where(x => checkNull(x.OperatingSystem).Contains(filterValue)).Union(query);
        }

        if (filterLower.Contains("lastloggedinuser"))
        {
            query = alldevices.Where(x => checkNull(x.LastUser).Contains(filterValue)).Union(query);
        }            

        return query;
    }
```

This is what I used finally, as I wasn't allowed to use an external dll, even though the predicate builder was an apt solution for my scenario.