# Expression Tree Errors as IQueryable but works as IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

My first foray into expression trees with a LINQ query has got me stuck.  Here is the query that works without an expression tree:

```
IQueryable<SampleResult> samples = samples.Select(a => new
{
   a = a,
   innerQuery = _dc.RequestedTests
   .SelectMany(
       b => _dc.ResultData.Where(x => (x.TestNum == b.TestNum && b.SampleID == a.SampleID))
       .DefaultIfEmpty(),
       (b, c) => new RequestedTestsJoinedResultData
       {
            RequestedTests = b,
            ResultData = c
       }).Where(joinedTable => ((joinedTable.ResultData.ResultID == 1) &&
                                (joinedTable.RequestedTests.TestID == 38) &&
                                (joinedTable.ResultData.IntValue >= (Int32?) 90))
    ).Select(joinedTable => joinedTable.RequestedTests.SampleID)
}).Where(temp0 => temp0.innerQuery.Contains(temp0.a.SampleID)).Select(temp0 => temp0.a);
```

My next move was to construct an expression tree to send to the the middle `Where()` call.  The expression tree is needed to dynamically create a filter based on user input.

```
var joinedTableParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(RequestedTestsJoinedResultData), 
    "joinedTable");

var left = Expression.Property(joinedTableParameter,
    typeof(RequestedTestsJoinedResultData).GetProperty("ResultData"));
left = Expression.Property(left,
    typeof(ResultData).GetProperty("ResultID"));
var rightConstant = Expression.Constant(resultFilter.ResultID);
Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(left, rightConstant);

left = Expression.Property(joinedTableParameter, typeof(RequestedTestsJoinedResultData)
    .GetProperty("RequestedTests"));
left = Expression.Property(left, typeof(RequestedTests)
    .GetProperty("TestID"));
rightConstant = Expression.Constant(resultFilter.TestID);
Expression e2 = Expression.Equal(left, rightConstant);

var preditcateBody = Expression.AndAlso(e1, e2);

left = Expression.Property(joinedTableParameter, typeof(RequestedTestsJoinedResultData)
    .GetProperty("ResultData"));
left = Expression.Property(left, typeof(ResultData)
    .GetProperty(comparisonColumn));
rightConstant = Expression.Constant(resultFilter.ResultValue, type);
Expression e3 = Expression.MakeBinary(resultFilter.ResultComparison, 
    left, rightConstant);

preditcateBody = Expression.AndAlso(preditcateBody, e3);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<RequestedTestsJoinedResultData, bool>>
    (preditcateBody, joinedTableParameter);
```

The first code block then changes from this:

```
.Where(joinedTable => ((joinedTable.ResultData.ResultID == 1) &&
                       (joinedTable.RequestedTests.TestID == 38) &&
                       (joinedTable.ResultData.IntValue >= (Int32?)90))
```

To This:

```
.Where(lambda)
```

The first code block works as `IQueryable` but when using the expression tree, the 2nd code block, it only works if I change it to `IEnumerable`.  I get this run-time error when using `IQueryable`:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   System.Data.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unsupported overload used for query operator
>   'Where'.

Stacktrace:

> at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
>   mc)\r\n    at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression
>   node)\r\n    at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.ConvertOuter(Expression
>   node)\r\n    at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query,
>   SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)\r\n    at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query)\r\n    at
>   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()\r\n
>   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()"

**EDITS:**

## 1: My custom data model class:

```
public class RequestedTestsJoinedResultData
{
    public virtual RequestedTests RequestedTests { get; set; }
    public virtual ResultData ResultData { get; set; }
}
```

## 2: DebugView of the lambdas:

Where clause lambda **dynamically** created from expression tree:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.RequestedTestsJoinedResultData,System.Boolean]>
(SoDak.Domain.Models.RequestedTestsJoinedResultData $joinedTable) 
($joinedTable.ResultDataTable).ResultID == 1 &&  
($joinedTable.RequestedTestsTable).TestID == 38 &&  
($joinedTable.ResultDataTable).IntValue >=  
.Constant<System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]>(90)
```

Large lambda with **hard coded** result filters:

```
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where( .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.SelectMany( .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
    .Constant(Table(Samples)), '(.Lambda #Lambda1)), '(.Lambda #Lambda2),
    '(.Lambda #Lambda3)), '(.Lambda #Lambda4f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]]]>)) ,
    '(.Lambda #Lambda5f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],System.Boolean]>)) ,
    '(.Lambda #Lambda6f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult]>)) ,
    '(.Lambda #Lambda7f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]]]>)) ,
    '(.Lambda #Lambda8f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],System.Boolean]>)) ,
    '(.Lambda #Lambda9f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult]>))
    .Lambda #Lambda1(SoDak.Domain.Samples $a) {
    ($a.StatusID == (System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])3 ||
    $a.StatusID == (System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])4) &&
    $a.Lab == .Constantc__DisplayClass24_0>(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService+<>c__DisplayClass24_0).labID }
    .Lambda #Lambda2(SoDak.Domain.Samples $a) {
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.DefaultIfEmpty(
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where( (.Constant(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService)._dc).CustomFields, '(.Lambda #Lambda10))) 
    }
    .Lambda #Lambda3( SoDak.Domain.Samples $a, SoDak.Domain.CustomFields $b) {
    .New SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult(){
    LabCount = (System.Int32)$a.LabCount, SampleID = $a.SampleID,
    AccountID = (System.Int32)$a.AccountID,Received = (System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])(($a.Received).Value).Date,
    Completed = (System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])(($a.Completed).Value).Date,
    SpeciesID = (System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])$a.SpeciesID,
    SpeciesCommonName = ($a.SeedNames).CommonName,StatusID = (System.Int32)$a.StatusID,
    StatusName = ($a.SampleStatus).StatusName,Variety = $a.Variety,Lot = $a.Lot,
    CarryOver = $a.CarryOver,Lab = (System.Int32)$a.Lab,LabID = (System.Int32)$a.Lab,
    TestList = $a.TestList,CustomFieldName = $b.CustomFieldName,CustomFieldNameValue = $b.CustomFieldNameValue
    }
    } .Lambda #Lambda4f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]]]>(SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult $a) {
    .New <>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]](
    $a, .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select( .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where( (.Constant(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService)._dc).SubAccounts,
    '(.Lambda #Lambda11)), '(.Lambda #Lambda12))) }
    .Lambda #Lambda5f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],
    System.Boolean]>(<>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,
    System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]] $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0) {
    ($<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.a).AccountID == .Constantc__DisplayClass24_0>(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService+<>c__DisplayClass24_0).accountIDLoggedIn ||
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Contains( $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.innerQuery,
    .Constantc__DisplayClass24_0>(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService+<>c__DisplayClass24_0).accountIDLoggedIn) }
    .Lambda #Lambda6f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],
    SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult]>(<>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]] $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0) {
    $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.a } .Lambda #Lambda7f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]]]>(
    SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult $a) { .New <>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]](
    $a, .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select( .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where( .Call System.Linq.Queryable.SelectMany(
    (.Constant(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService)._dc).RequestedTests, '(.Lambda #Lambda13), '(.Lambda #Lambda14)) , '(.Lambda #Lambda15)), '(.Lambda #Lambda16))) }
    .Lambda #Lambda8f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],System.Boolean]>(<>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]] $temp0) {
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Contains( $temp0.innerQuery, ($temp0.a).SampleID) }
    .Lambda #Lambda9f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult]>(<>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]] $temp0) { $temp0.a }
    .Lambda #Lambda10(SoDak.Domain.CustomFields $x) {
    $x.SampleID == $a.SampleID && $x.OnReport == (System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean])True } .Lambda #Lambda11(SoDak.Domain.SubAccounts $b) {
    $b.SampleID == $a.SampleID } .Lambda #Lambda12(SoDak.Domain.SubAccounts $b) { $b.AccountID } .Lambda #Lambda13(SoDak.Domain.RequestedTests $b) {
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.DefaultIfEmpty(.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where( (.Constant(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService)._dc).ResultData, '(.Lambda #Lambda17))) }
    .Lambda #Lambda14( SoDak.Domain.RequestedTests $b, SoDak.Domain.ResultData $c) { .New SoDak.Domain.Models.RequestedTestsJoinedResultData(){
    RequestedTestsTable = $b, ResultDataTable = $c } } .Lambda #Lambda15(SoDak.Domain.Models.RequestedTestsJoinedResultData $joinedTable) {
    $joinedTable != null && ($joinedTable.ResultDataTable).ResultID == 1 && ($joinedTable.RequestedTestsTable).TestID == 38 && ($joinedTable.ResultDataTable).IntValue >= (System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])90 }
    .Lambda #Lambda16(SoDak.Domain.Models.RequestedTestsJoinedResultData $joinedTable) { ($joinedTable.RequestedTestsTable).SampleID } 
    .Lambda #Lambda17(SoDak.Domain.ResultData $x) { $x.TestNum == $b.TestNum && $b.SampleID == $a.SampleID }
```

Large lambda with **dynamically created** result filters by expression tree building.

```
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.SelectMany(
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
.Constant(Table(Samples)),
'(.Lambda #Lambda1)), '(.Lambda #Lambda2), '(.Lambda #Lambda3)),
'(.Lambda #Lambda4f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]]]>)) ,
'(.Lambda #Lambda5f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],System.Boolean]>)) ,
'(.Lambda #Lambda6f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult]>)) ,
'(.Lambda #Lambda7f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]]]>)) ,
'(.Lambda #Lambda8f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],System.Boolean]>)) ,
'(.Lambda #Lambda9f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult]>))
.Lambda #Lambda1(SoDak.Domain.Samples $a) { ($a.StatusID == (System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])3 || $a.StatusID == (System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])4) &&
$a.Lab == .Constantc__DisplayClass24_0>(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService+<>c__DisplayClass24_0).labID }
.Lambda #Lambda2(SoDak.Domain.Samples $a) {
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.DefaultIfEmpty(.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where( (.Constant(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService)._dc).CustomFields, '(.Lambda #Lambda10))) }
.Lambda #Lambda3( SoDak.Domain.Samples $a, SoDak.Domain.CustomFields $b) {
.New SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult(){
LabCount = (System.Int32)$a.LabCount,
SampleID = $a.SampleID, AccountID = (System.Int32)$a.AccountID,
Received = (System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])(($a.Received).Value).Date,
Completed = (System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])(($a.Completed).Value).Date,
SpeciesID = (System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])$a.SpeciesID,
SpeciesCommonName = ($a.SeedNames).CommonName,StatusID = (System.Int32)$a.StatusID,
StatusName = ($a.SampleStatus).StatusName,Variety = $a.Variety, Lot = $a.Lot,
CarryOver = $a.CarryOver,Lab = (System.Int32)$a.Lab,LabID = (System.Int32)$a.Lab,
TestList = $a.TestList,CustomFieldName = $b.CustomFieldName,CustomFieldNameValue = $b.CustomFieldNameValue } }
.Lambda #Lambda4f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]]]>(SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult $a) {
.New <>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]](
$a,
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where( (.Constant(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService)._dc).SubAccounts,
'(.Lambda #Lambda11)), '(.Lambda #Lambda12))) }
.Lambda #Lambda5f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],System.Boolean]>
(<>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]] $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0) {
($<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.a).AccountID == .Constantc__DisplayClass24_0>(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService+<>c__DisplayClass24_0).accountIDLoggedIn ||
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Contains( $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.innerQuery, .Constantc__DisplayClass24_0>(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService+<>c__DisplayClass24_0).accountIDLoggedIn) }
.Lambda #Lambda6f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult]>(<>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]] $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0) { $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.a }
.Lambda #Lambda7f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]]]>(SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult $a) { .New <>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]](
$a, .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.SelectMany( (.Constant(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService)._dc).RequestedTests,
'(.Lambda #Lambda13), '(.Lambda #Lambda14)) ,
.Constantc__DisplayClass24_1>(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService+<>c__DisplayClass24_1).lambda) ,
'(.Lambda #Lambda15))) } .Lambda #Lambda8f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],System.Boolean]>(<>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]] $temp0) {
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Contains( $temp0.innerQuery, ($temp0.a).SampleID) }
.Lambda #Lambda9f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult]>(<>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]] $temp0) {
$temp0.a }
.Lambda #Lambda10(SoDak.Domain.CustomFields $x) {
$x.SampleID == $a.SampleID && $x.OnReport == (System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean])True }
.Lambda #Lambda11(SoDak.Domain.SubAccounts $b) { $b.SampleID == $a.SampleID }
.Lambda #Lambda12(SoDak.Domain.SubAccounts $b) { $b.AccountID }
.Lambda #Lambda13(SoDak.Domain.RequestedTests $b) {
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.DefaultIfEmpty(.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where( (.Constant(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService)._dc).ResultData, '(.Lambda #Lambda16))) }
.Lambda #Lambda14( SoDak.Domain.RequestedTests $b, SoDak.Domain.ResultData $c) {
.New SoDak.Domain.Models.RequestedTestsJoinedResultData(){ RequestedTestsTable = $b, ResultDataTable = $c } }
.Lambda #Lambda15(SoDak.Domain.Models.RequestedTestsJoinedResultData $joinedTable) {
($joinedTable.RequestedTestsTable).SampleID } 
.Lambda #Lambda16(SoDak.Domain.ResultData $x) { $x.TestNum == $b.TestNum && $b.SampleID == $a.SampleID }
```

## 3: I went ahead and tried the same query using `System.Linq.Dynamic` and got another error which may or may not be related.

The where clause using dynamic LINQ:

```
.Where("joinedTable => " + 
"((joinedTable.ResultDataTable.ResultID == " + resultFilter.ResultID + ") && " +
"(joinedTable.RequestedTestsTable.TestID == " + resultFilter.TestID + ") && " +
"(joinedTable.ResultDataTable." + resultFilter.ResultType + " >= " + 
resultFilter.ResultValueString + "))")
```

Error:

> Member access 'SoDak.Domain.RequestedTests RequestedTestsTable' of
>   'SoDak.Domain.Models.RequestedTestsJoinedResultData' not legal on type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[SoDak.Domain.Models.RequestedTestsJoinedResultData].

## 4: Generated SQL when result filters are hard coded:

```
SELECT [t4].[SampleID], [t4].[value] AS [LabCount], [t4].[value2] AS [Lab], [t4].[value3] AS [LabID], [t4].[value4] AS [AccountID], [t4].[value5] AS [Received], [t4].[value6] AS [Completed], [t4].[value7] AS [SpeciesID], [t4].[CommonName] AS [SpeciesCommonName], [t4].[value8] AS [StatusID], [t4].[StatusName], [t4].[Variety], [t4].[Lot], [t4].[CarryOver], [t4].[TestList], [t4].[value9] AS [CustomFieldName], [t4].[value10] AS [CustomFieldNameValue]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[SampleID], [t0].[LabCount] AS [value], [t0].[Lab] AS [value2], [t0].[Lab] AS [value3], [t0].[AccountID] AS [value4], CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[Received]) AS [value5], CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[Completed]) AS [value6], [t0].[SpeciesID] AS [value7], [t2].[CommonName], [t0].[StatusID] AS [value8], [t3].[StatusName], [t0].[Variety], [t0].[Lot], [t0].[CarryOver], [t0].[TestList], [t1].[CustomFieldName] AS [value9], [t1].[CustomFieldNameValue] AS [value10], [t0].[StatusID], [t0].[Lab]
    FROM [Samples].[Samples] AS [t0]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Web].[CustomFields] AS [t1] ON ([t1].[SampleID] = [t0].[SampleID]) AND ([t1].[OnReport] = @p0)
    INNER JOIN [Seeds].[SeedNames] AS [t2] ON [t2].[SpeciesID] = [t0].[SpeciesID]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Lookup].[SampleStatus] AS [t3] ON [t3].[StatusID] = [t0].[StatusID]
    ) AS [t4]
WHERE (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [Samples].[RequestedTests] AS [t5]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Results].[ResultData] AS [t6] ON ([t6].[TestNum] = [t5].[TestNum]) AND ([t5].[SampleID] = [t4].[SampleID])
    WHERE ([t5].[SampleID] = [t4].[SampleID]) AND ([t6].[ResultID] = @p1) AND ([t5].[TestID] = @p2) AND ([t6].[IntValue] >= @p3)
    )) AND (([t4].[value4] = @p4) OR (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [Samples].[SubAccounts] AS [t7]
    WHERE ([t7].[AccountID] = @p5) AND ([t7].[SampleID] = [t4].[SampleID])
    ))) AND (([t4].[StatusID] = @p6) OR ([t4].[StatusID] = @p7)) AND ([t4].[Lab] = @p8)
```

Is it truly not supported or am I doing something wrong when I construct my expression tree?

Comment: My first question would be to make sure you actually need an expression tree.  But in concept from what you have appears correct to me. I would try not reusing the `predicateBody` variable.  Make a new one. `var preditcateBody2 = Expression.AndAlso(preditcateBody, e3);`

Comment: @RobertMcKee - thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately that didn't help and I get the same error.  I'm using an expression tree to construct the filter based on user input and avoid using the `DynamicQuery` library.

Comment: Can you try to add only one expression at a time... e1 only, e1 and e2, e1 and e2 and e3. Perhaps you already did it and no matter what you get the same error?

Comment: its hard to say something, because it is unclear what is of what type, but im guessing, that the wrong Where is used, e.g Where(Expression<Func>) instead of Where(Func), might that be the case? what is the type of RequestedTestsJoinedResultData? is that iqueryable? compare the resulting expression trees (especially the where call), is it the same?

Comment: @JonathanMagnan - thanks for the idea but that didn't work either.  @MBoros - You might be onto something here.  I've added my `RequestedTestsJoinedResultData` class.  It is just a simple data model class that I am not sure implements IQueryable.  It is just a representation of the two classes representing my database tables joined together.  If this class doesn't implement IQueryable please advise how it would or how to accomplish my query using an anonymous type.

Comment: @jaredbaszler Does this answer not help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675568/dynamic-filtering-using-linq (Assuming you change the signature to `private static IQueryable<SampleResult> FilterSampleResultList(IQueryable<SampleResult> sampleResult, SampleResultFilter filter)` or write an extension method like `public static IQueryable<SampleResult> Filter(this IQueryable<SampleResult> sampleResult, SampleResultFilter filter)`

Comment: @jaredbaszler can you show what the DebugView of the lambda expression is?

Comment: @RobertMcKee - thanks for the link but I can't figure out a way to chain where clauses like that post suggests since the clause I want to make dynamic is tied to the `innerQuery` which is tied to the outer query in the first where clause.

Comment: @jaredbaszler I meant the text in the `DebugView` property (only viewable when debugging). You can see the beginning of it in your screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, the `DebugView` of the outer lambda `samples`. The one you posted appears fine.

Comment: @jaredbaszler Sorry, I meant `samples.Expression` which is an expression of some sort.

Comment: So is that the DebugView of the lambda with compiler generated expressions? Or with you trying to dynamically generate it? (I would like both). Basically just want to diff them.

Comment: ...and lastly we'll need the debugview for variable `lambda` from the dynamic side.

Comment: @Shlomo - thanks again for taking a look.  I'm attempting a different angle while we are at it.

Comment: @Shlomo - Stop your efforts - I figured it out.  Thanks again for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up breaking up the complex inner query and that solved my issue.  Using `IEnumerable` and filtering on our entire `ResultData` table was taking over 90 seconds.  Getting `IQueryable` to work dropped that down to less than .5 seconds.

You will need to decipher the top part of my original post above to see what I changed from there to here.

```
var innerQuery = (from a in _dc.RequestedTests
    from b in _dc.ResultData
        .Where(c => a.TestNum == c.TestNum)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new RequestedTestsJoinedResultData
    {
        RequestedTestsTable = a,
        ResultDataTable = b
    }).Where(lambda).Select(a => a.RequestedTestsTable.SampleID);

samples = samples.Where(a => innerQuery.Contains(a.SampleID));
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

I think what was tripping you up was your handling of nullable filters. If you wrap an `Expression.Constant` around a nullable double (or int), I'm not sure it will compile nicely.

Here's the two DebugViews of the lambdas pretty-printed:

---

**Long answer**

**Hard coded**

```
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
   .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
      .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
         .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
            .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
               .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
                  .Call System.Linq.Queryable.SelectMany(
                     .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
                        .Constant(Table(Samples)),
                        '(.Lambda #Lambda1)
                     ), 
                     '(.Lambda #Lambda2), 
                     '(.Lambda #Lambda3)
                  ),
                  '(.Lambda #Lambda4f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]]]>)
               ),
               '(.Lambda #Lambda5f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],System.Boolean]>)
            ),
            '(.Lambda #Lambda6f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult]>)
         ),
         '(.Lambda #Lambda7f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]]]>)
      ),
      '(.Lambda #Lambda8f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],System.Boolean]>)
   ),
   '(.Lambda #Lambda9f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult]>)
)

.Lambda #Lambda1(SoDak.Domain.Samples $a) {
   ($a.StatusID == (System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])3 || $a.StatusID == (System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])4) &&
      $a.Lab == .Constantc__DisplayClass24_0>(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService+<>c__DisplayClass24_0).labID 
}

.Lambda #Lambda2(SoDak.Domain.Samples $a) {
   .Call System.Linq.Queryable.DefaultIfEmpty(
      .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where( 
         (.Constant(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService)._dc).CustomFields, 
         '(.Lambda #Lambda10)
      )
   ) 
}

.Lambda #Lambda3( SoDak.Domain.Samples $a, SoDak.Domain.CustomFields $b) {
   .New SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult(){
      LabCount = (System.Int32)$a.LabCount,
      SampleID = $a.SampleID,
      AccountID = (System.Int32)$a.AccountID,
      Received = (System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])(($a.Received).Value).Date,
      Completed = (System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])(($a.Completed).Value).Date,
      SpeciesID = (System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])$a.SpeciesID,
      SpeciesCommonName = ($a.SeedNames).CommonName,
      StatusID = (System.Int32)$a.StatusID,
      StatusName = ($a.SampleStatus).StatusName,
      Variety = $a.Variety,
      Lot = $a.Lot,
      CarryOver = $a.CarryOver,
      Lab = (System.Int32)$a.Lab,
      LabID = (System.Int32)$a.Lab,
      TestList = $a.TestList,
      CustomFieldName = $b.CustomFieldName,
      CustomFieldNameValue = $b.CustomFieldNameValue
   }
}

.Lambda #Lambda4f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]]]>(SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult $a) {
   .New <>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]](
      $a,
      .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
         .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where( 
            (.Constant(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService)._dc).SubAccounts,
            '(.Lambda #Lambda11)
         ), 
         '(.Lambda #Lambda12)
      )
   ) 
}

.Lambda #Lambda5f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],System.Boolean]>(<>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]] $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0) {
   ($<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.a).AccountID == .Constantc__DisplayClass24_0>(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService+<>c__DisplayClass24_0).accountIDLoggedIn ||
   .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Contains( 
      $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.innerQuery,
      .Constantc__DisplayClass24_0>(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService+<>c__DisplayClass24_0).accountIDLoggedIn
   ) 
}

.Lambda #Lambda6f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult]>(<>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]] $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0) {
   $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.a 
}

.Lambda #Lambda7f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]]]>(
   SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult $a) { 
   .New <>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]](
      $a, 
      .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
         .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
            .Call System.Linq.Queryable.SelectMany(
               (.Constant(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService)._dc).RequestedTests, 
               '(.Lambda #Lambda13), 
               '(.Lambda #Lambda14)
            ), 
            '(.Lambda #Lambda15)
         ), 
         '(.Lambda #Lambda16)
      )
   ) 
}

.Lambda #Lambda8f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],System.Boolean]>(<>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]] $temp0) {
   .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Contains( 
      $temp0.innerQuery, 
      ($temp0.a).SampleID
   )
}

.Lambda #Lambda9f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult]>(<>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]] $temp0) { 
   $temp0.a 
}

.Lambda #Lambda10(SoDak.Domain.CustomFields $x) {
   $x.SampleID == $a.SampleID && 
      $x.OnReport == (System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean])True 
}

.Lambda #Lambda11(SoDak.Domain.SubAccounts $b) {
   $b.SampleID == $a.SampleID 
}

.Lambda #Lambda12(SoDak.Domain.SubAccounts $b) {
   $b.AccountID
}

.Lambda #Lambda13(SoDak.Domain.RequestedTests $b) {
   .Call System.Linq.Queryable.DefaultIfEmpty(
      .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where( 
         (.Constant(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService)._dc).ResultData, 
         '(.Lambda #Lambda17)
      )
   )
}

.Lambda #Lambda14( SoDak.Domain.RequestedTests $b, SoDak.Domain.ResultData $c) {
   .New SoDak.Domain.Models.RequestedTestsJoinedResultData(){
      RequestedTestsTable = $b,
      ResultDataTable = $c
   }
}

.Lambda #Lambda16(SoDak.Domain.Models.RequestedTestsJoinedResultData $joinedTable) {
   ($joinedTable.RequestedTestsTable).SampleID
}

.Lambda #Lambda17(SoDak.Domain.ResultData $x) {
   $x.TestNum == $b.TestNum &&
      $b.SampleID == $a.SampleID
}

.Lambda #Lambda15(SoDak.Domain.Models.RequestedTestsJoinedResultData $joinedTable) {
   $joinedTable != null && 
      ($joinedTable.ResultDataTable).ResultID == 1 && 
      ($joinedTable.RequestedTestsTable).TestID == 38 && 
      ($joinedTable.ResultDataTable).IntValue >= (System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])90 
}
```

**Dynamic with the lambda at the end**

```
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
   .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
      .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
         .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
            .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
               .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
                  .Call System.Linq.Queryable.SelectMany(
                     .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
                        .Constant(Table(Samples)),
                        '(.Lambda #Lambda1)
                     ), 
                     '(.Lambda #Lambda2), 
                     '(.Lambda #Lambda3)
                  ),
                  '(.Lambda #Lambda4f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]]]>)
               ),
               '(.Lambda #Lambda5f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],System.Boolean]>)
            ),
            '(.Lambda #Lambda6f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult]>)
         ),
         '(.Lambda #Lambda7f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]]]>)
      ),
      '(.Lambda #Lambda8f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],System.Boolean]>)
   ),
   '(.Lambda #Lambda9f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult]>)
)

.Lambda #Lambda1(SoDak.Domain.Samples $a) {
   ($a.StatusID == (System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])3 || $a.StatusID == (System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])4) &&
      $a.Lab == .Constantc__DisplayClass24_0>(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService+<>c__DisplayClass24_0).labID 
}

.Lambda #Lambda2(SoDak.Domain.Samples $a) {
   .Call System.Linq.Queryable.DefaultIfEmpty(
      .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where( 
         (.Constant(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService)._dc).CustomFields, 
         '(.Lambda #Lambda10)
      )
   ) 
}

.Lambda #Lambda3( SoDak.Domain.Samples $a, SoDak.Domain.CustomFields $b) {
   .New SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult(){
      LabCount = (System.Int32)$a.LabCount,
      SampleID = $a.SampleID,
      AccountID = (System.Int32)$a.AccountID,
      Received = (System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])(($a.Received).Value).Date,
      Completed = (System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])(($a.Completed).Value).Date,
      SpeciesID = (System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])$a.SpeciesID,
      SpeciesCommonName = ($a.SeedNames).CommonName,
      StatusID = (System.Int32)$a.StatusID,
      StatusName = ($a.SampleStatus).StatusName,
      Variety = $a.Variety,
      Lot = $a.Lot,
      CarryOver = $a.CarryOver,
      Lab = (System.Int32)$a.Lab,
      LabID = (System.Int32)$a.Lab,
      TestList = $a.TestList,
      CustomFieldName = $b.CustomFieldName,
      CustomFieldNameValue = $b.CustomFieldNameValue
   }
}

.Lambda #Lambda4f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]]]>(SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult $a) {
   .New <>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]](
      $a,
      .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
         .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where( 
            (.Constant(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService)._dc).SubAccounts,
            '(.Lambda #Lambda11)
         ), 
         '(.Lambda #Lambda12)
      )
   ) 
}

.Lambda #Lambda5f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],System.Boolean]>(<>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]] $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0) {
   ($<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.a).AccountID == .Constantc__DisplayClass24_0>(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService+<>c__DisplayClass24_0).accountIDLoggedIn ||
   .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Contains( 
      $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.innerQuery,
      .Constantc__DisplayClass24_0>(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService+<>c__DisplayClass24_0).accountIDLoggedIn
   ) 
}

.Lambda #Lambda6f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult]>(<>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]] $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0) {
   $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.a 
}

.Lambda #Lambda7f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]]]>(SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult $a) { 
   .New <>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]](
      $a, 
      .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
         .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
            .Call System.Linq.Queryable.SelectMany(
               (.Constant(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService)._dc).RequestedTests,
               '(.Lambda #Lambda13), 
               '(.Lambda #Lambda14)
            ),
            .Constantc__DisplayClass24_1>(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService+<>c__DisplayClass24_1).lambda
         ),
         '(.Lambda #Lambda15)
      )
   ) 
}

.Lambda #Lambda8f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],System.Boolean]>(<>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]] $temp0) {
   .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Contains( 
      $temp0.innerQuery, 
      ($temp0.a).SampleID
   )
}

.Lambda #Lambda9f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]],SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult]>(<>f__AnonymousType1`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.SampleResult,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]] $temp0) {
   $temp0.a 
}

.Lambda #Lambda10(SoDak.Domain.CustomFields $x) {
   $x.SampleID == $a.SampleID && 
      $x.OnReport == (System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean])True 
}

.Lambda #Lambda11(SoDak.Domain.SubAccounts $b) {
   $b.SampleID == $a.SampleID 
}

.Lambda #Lambda12(SoDak.Domain.SubAccounts $b) {
   $b.AccountID
}
.Lambda #Lambda13(SoDak.Domain.RequestedTests $b) {
   .Call System.Linq.Queryable.DefaultIfEmpty(
      .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where( 
         (.Constant(SoDak.Domain.Services.SampleService)._dc).ResultData, 
         '(.Lambda #Lambda16)
      )
   )
}

.Lambda #Lambda14( SoDak.Domain.RequestedTests $b, SoDak.Domain.ResultData $c) {
   .New SoDak.Domain.Models.RequestedTestsJoinedResultData(){
      RequestedTestsTable = $b,
      ResultDataTable = $c
   }
}

.Lambda #Lambda15(SoDak.Domain.Models.RequestedTestsJoinedResultData $joinedTable) {
   ($joinedTable.RequestedTestsTable).SampleID
}

.Lambda #Lambda16(SoDak.Domain.ResultData $x) {
   $x.TestNum == $b.TestNum &&
      $b.SampleID == $a.SampleID
}

.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[SoDak.Domain.Models.RequestedTestsJoinedResultData,System.Boolean]>(SoDak.Domain.Models.RequestedTestsJoinedResultData $joinedTable) 
   ($joinedTable.ResultDataTable).ResultID == 1 &&  
      ($joinedTable.RequestedTestsTable).TestID == 38 &&  
      ($joinedTable.ResultDataTable).IntValue >=  .Constant<System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]>(90)
```

If you diff these two text-walls, you'll see they're almost identical. The numbering of the lambdas changes inconsequentially. There are a couple things popping out at me:

1. On the dynamic side, the lambda is contained in a closure. Best to make sure that the variable `lambda` isn't being re-used. If it is, that will affect your expression.
2. The hard-coded side has a null-check, the dynamic side doesn't.
3. It looks like for the last comparison, the hard-coded side is casting the comparing `.IntValue` to `int?` and the dynamic side is passing a constant `int?`. I think this is the source of your problems.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for looking into this.  Your solutions certainly make sense and hopefully will help someone else in the future.  If I could transfer some points to you I would!