# Create null enumerable within Linq to Entities query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project which uses Entity Framework.

I need to project values pulled from the database into a `PropertyValue` type, which looks like the following:

```
public class PropertyValue {
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    public bool? BoolValue { get; set; }
    public int? IntValue { get; set; }
}
```

Most of the time, this is easy enough. To filter all users with "First Name" = "John" and "Is Archived" = true, I could do:

```
usersQuery
    .Where(u => 
        new PropertyValue {
            StringValue = u.FirstName,
            BoolValue = null,
            IntValue = null
        }.StringValue == "John")
    .Where(u =>
        new PropertyValue {
            StringValue = null,
            BoolValue = u.IsArchived,
            IntValue = null
        }.BoolValue == true);
```

Obviously this is a ridiculous looking query, but I'm constructing these queries piece by piece based on user input. These queries need to be combinable, which is why I have to explicitly set all the unused properties of `PropertyValue` to null, and I have to set them all in the same order. If I don't do this, I'll get an error from Entity Framework saying that PropertyValue exists in two structurally incompatible initializations within the query.

> System.NotSupportedException: The type 'UMS.Utilities.PropertyValue' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.

This isn't a problem, I can just make sure all the properties are explicitly set to null. The problem arises when I have to add another property to my `PropertyValue` type, to be able to retrieve a list of IDs (in my case, retrieving all selected roles for the user, i.e. "Admin", "Guardian", "Teacher", "Student")

I've modified my `PropertyValue` class to be able to store a list of Guids:

```
public class PropertyValue {
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    public bool? BoolValue { get; set; }
    public int? IntValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Guid> GuidValues { get; set; }
}
```

I can now query for user roles like so:

```
usersQuery
    .Select(u => new PropertyValue {
        StringValue = null,
        BoolValue = null,
        IntValue = null,
        GuidValues = u.UserRoles.Select(ur => ur.Role_ID)
    });
```

That works great. Pulling first names would now look like this:

```
usersQuery
    .Select(u => new PropertyValue {
        StringValue = u.FirstName,
        BoolValue = null,
        IntValue = null,
        GuidValues = null
    });
```

But I get the following error:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.

So I can't create a null enumerable within EF. But I can't just ignore the initialization of the property, or else I get the structurally incompatible error. I've tried doing `GuidValues = Enumerable.Empty<Guid>()` instead, but I can't do that in an EF context either.

How can I get around this issue and create a null or empty enumerable within an EF projection?

Comment: Side note: Since `BoolValue` and `IntValue` are nullable, there is no need to use `BoolValue = null,` and `ntValue = null,` (they are already `null`)

Comment: No, I need to explicitly set them, see my remarks about the structurally incompatible error for Entity Framework

Comment: In case of _null_ just set  `GuidValues = new List<Guid>();`

Comment: What do you mean by _These queries need to be combinable,_? What is it your doing?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I am building an interface for school administrators to create a custom report. So they could say they want all users where "Last Name" is equal to Smith, and "Is Archived" is equal to false. I expose it all in a very simple, user-friendly interface, and then on the backend I deal with actually translating it into a query.

Comment: But the code you have shown will not throw that error. What is the code your using?

Comment: @StephenMuecke that is correct. The code I posted might be oversimplified. In my actual code, I will have multiple projections in the same query. So in the example of "Last Name" equal to Smith and "Is Archived" equal to false, I would project a PropertyValue with the StringValue set to u.LastName, as well as a PropertyValue with the BoolValue set to u.IsArchived. Does that make sense?

Comment: Edit your question with an example of the code you are using that throws that exception.

Comment: @HariPrasad, your suggestion does not work within a Linq-to-Entities query.

Comment: @jamebob Okay, this is unrelated to your actual issue, but it may be a step towards solving it. You don't need to select columns *twice*. If you want to filter data, you want to restrict it with `Where()` and (most likely) return the whole row, regardless of what they filtered. If they want to see unarchived students, that doesn't mean they only want to see the 'isArchived' column. Your query *should* look something like this: `students.Where(s => s.LastName == "Smith").Where(s => !s.IsArchived);`. Whether or not you apply a select shouldn't affect filtering data.

Comment: @jamebob See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675568/dynamic-filtering-using-linq) for an example of filtering

Comment: @StephenMuecke see my edits, the new example I gave should fail with the error that I described if you leave out the null initializers.

Comment: To _filter all users with "First Name" = "John" and "Is Archived" = true_ then the query is simply `usersQuery.Where(x => x.FirstName == "John" && x.IsArchived);`

Comment: @Rob I edited my question to use `Where` instead of `Select` so that I would describe a scenario similar to your comment. I understand where you are coming from with the link you gave, but because of the generic solution I am trying to come up with I don't think it will work in my case.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, yours is obviously a much better query if I were hard-coding this. But please refer to what I said right underneath that query: *Obviously this is a ridiculous looking query, but I'm constructing these queries piece by piece based on user input.*

Comment: @jamebob Your new edit to me, doesn't need to be projected into `PropertyValue`. There's no reason to construct `PropertyValue` just to use the value you're setting it to anyway. If you're able to generically write `new PropertyValue { StringValue = u.FirstName }.StringValue == 'Test'`, you're also able to generically write `u.FirstName == 'Test'`. There isn't really any benefit to it. If anything, introducing `PropertyValue` makes the solution *less* generic

Comment: @jamebob, You need to give a bit more information on what your really trying to do. Best guess is that you filtering data on the client side and passing back values for `FirstName` and `IsArchived` which could be `null`? In which case you test the values and do `if(FirstName.HasValue) { usersQuery = usersQuery.Where(u => u.FirstName == firstName); } if (IsArchived.HasValue) { usersQuery = usersQuery.Where(u => u.IsArchived); }` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke  I can't very concisely explain all the facets of what I'm trying to do and how I've arrived at some of the design decisions that I have. I am trying to do filtering similar to what you are describing, but in a way that is even more generic - I want this feature I'm working on to allow users to generate reports on other types of data as well, not just users within the system. The heart of my question is this: given that I have to combine queries which project values into a certain type, is there any way that I can instantiate a null IEnumerable property on that type?

Comment: Sorry to be so vague

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about the use case. But speaking generally, I agree that it's annoying EF limitation, especially the reasoning behind the *structurally incompatible initializations* requirement, which forces us to use an ugly workaround I'm going to propose you.

Shortly, there is no way to workaround the *null enumerable* assignment other than **not including** the assignment into projection. The next is an attempt to workaround the *structurally incompatible initializations* problem. It works in most cases except in `Concat` / `Union` scenarios.

Start by defining a couple subclasses:

```
public class StringPropertyValue : PropertyValue { }
public class BoolPropertyValue : PropertyValue { }
public class IntPropertyValue : PropertyValue { }
public class GuidsPropertyValue : PropertyValue { }
```

The names does not really matter because no special constraints are put on those classes, the only important thing is they to be **different**. We'll use those classes for projection instead of `PropertyValue`.

Then we'll need another simple class like this:

```
public class Property
{
    public PropertyValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

It's needed to workaround another EF limitation - unsupported *casts*. In order to project a `PropertyValue`, instead of unsupported

```
(PropertyValue)new StringPropertyValue { StringValue = .. }
```

we will perform the cast by using the ugly but supported

```
new Property { Value = new StringPropertyValue { StringValue = ... } }.Value
```

And that's it.

Here are the equivalent working versions of your examples:

(1)

```
usersQuery
    .Where(u => new Property { Value = new StringPropertyValue {
            StringValue = u.FirstName
        }}.Value.StringValue == "John")
    .Where(u => new Property { Value = new BoolPropertyValue { 
            BoolValue = u.IsArchived
        }}.Value.BoolValue == true);
```

(2)

```
usersQuery
    .Select(u => new Property { Value = new GuidsPropertyValue {
        GuidValues = u.UserRoles.Select(ur => ur.Role_ID)
    }}.Value);
```

(3)

```
usersQuery
    .Select(u => new Property { Value = new StringPropertyValue {
        StringValue = u.FirstName
    }}.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan! The use case I described is very contrived, I was just trying to get it into a format where my problem was clear. I'll try out this solution today and see if it works for me!

Comment: Refactored some things to try out your solution and it's working great, thanks a lot!