# IQueryable Union, Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Int32

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to implement LINQ query to Entity Framework with union. Let's say I have 2 tables: Users and TempUsers. I try to:

```
var users = context.Users
        .Select(u => new UserModel 
        {
            Name = u.Name,
            Roles = u.Roles.Select(r => r.Id)
        })
    .Union(context.TempUsers
        .Select(u => new UserModel 
        {
            Name = u.Name,
            Roles = null
        }))
.ToList();
```

Model class:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting `NotSupportedException` with message:

> Unable to create a null constant value of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.
>   Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported
>   in this context.

If I remove `Roles = null`, I get `NotSupportedException` with message:

> The type 'UserModel' appears in two
>   structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to
>   Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same
>   query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and
>   those properties are set in the same order.

An ideas how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try removing `Roles=null` in your second query? I think you don't need to do that, both results are the same type

Comment: @octavioccl I did try it. Please see an updated question.

Comment: have you tried unioning them before you project into UserModel?

Comment: @octavioccl I guess it's not common to merge results from different tables to 1 model.

Comment: Can you update your question to show UserModel and especially the Roles type

Comment: @DamianGreen updated.

Comment: Try calling AsEnumerable extension method: `query1.AsEnumerable().Union(query2);`. The union is not going to be executed in the server side but it should solve your issue.

Comment: @octavioccl same exception (#1)

Comment: But also removing `Roles=null`? The exception i'm trying to avoid is the second one which is specific from EF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid those exceptions, you can do the union in memory calling `AsEnumerable` extension method:

```
var users = context.Users
        .Select(u => new UserModel 
        {
            Name = u.Name,
            Roles = u.Roles.Select(r => r.Id)
        })
        .AsEnumerable() //Add this 
        .Union(context.TempUsers
        .Select(u => new UserModel 
        {
            Name = u.Name,
        }))
.ToList();
```

The problem is your are trying to project with a DTO that have a complex type as a property. That doesn't let you assign a default value because EF only supports entity types, enumeration types or primitive types when you try to project a query. Also not worth use an anonymous type because both projections must be based in an anonymous type with the same property names, so, at the end is the same problem.

### Update

Now that I saw a solution using Inheritance, this idea came to my mind.

```
public TempUser
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
} 

public UserModel:TempUser
{
  public IEnumerable<int> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Then to try execute union in your server side, you will also need to call `OfType` extension method

```
var query=context.TempUsers
          .Select(u => new TempUser
          {
            Name = u.Name,
          })
          .Union(context.Users
          .Select(u => new UserModel 
          {
            Name = u.Name,
            Roles = u.Roles.Select(r => r.Id)
          }).OfType<TempUser>())
          .ToList();
```

The downside of this solution if the result will be a `List<TempUser>`

Comment: yes, actually this works. But... I need to perform sql query, not query to objects. This will be too slow on big data sets.

Comment: Yes, that's what I guess. The problem with what are you are trying to project is that `Role` is a complex type, you can't assign that property with a default value unless it be a query result like in your first query

Comment: ya.. right. Would anonymous type model make any difference, what do you think?

Comment: I don't think so. If you try with a anonymous type, which is supported,  projections must be based using the same property names, but the same is going to happen with your second query, because you can't assign a default value

Comment: makes sense. Please elaborate on this in your answer. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I would wish have a good solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

The first exception cannot be avoided, but the second can with the following trick.

Since EF complains that you initialize one and the same **type** differently, you can create and initialize a different type derived from the original one.

For instance:

```
public class TempUserModel : UserModel { }
```

and then

```
var users = context.Users
        .Select(u => new UserModel 
        {
            Name = u.Name,
            Roles = u.Roles.Select(r => r.Id)
        })
    .Union(context.TempUsers
        .Select(u => new TempUserModel 
        {
            Name = u.Name
        }))
    .ToList();
```

**UPDATE:** The above trick works for single value properties but not for collection type properties. And more importantly, it turns out that `Concat` / `Union` with nested subqueries are not supported at all. So the only way to do that in SQL is to perform the `Concat` (which btw is the equivalent of the SQL `UNION ALL`) master tables first, and then do conditional joins, but I'm not sure it does worth the effort. Better use some of the mixed approaches from the currently accepted answer.

Comment: I like the idea, but first I think he will need create a different hierarchy, also `OfType` extension method should be called somewhere.

Comment: @octavioccl No, this trick is just for projection. I was answering something similar before, just haven't time to find it. But now I did, so this really is duplicate of it - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106147/create-null-enumerable-within-linq-to-entities-query/37117208#37117208

Comment: I got your point, I didn't know about that ;), but what about the second exception? According to what I understand both projections should be done initializing the same properties.

Comment: @octavioccl That's the trick:) Only if they are one and the same type. And `UserModel`  != `TempUserModel`. All you need it to create as many derived types as you want and just call them differently.

Comment: @octavioccl But the trick works only for single item properties and not for collections :(