# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object)'

Tags: c#, linq

I have this method:

```
public IQueryable<T> List(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var queryString = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
    var models = _service.List();
    foreach(var item in queryString)
        models = models.Where(m => m.GetType().GetProperty(item.Key).GetValue(m).ToString().Contains(item.Value));
    return models;
}
```

And when I run it I get this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Which I have been unable to fix. Does anyone know how to fix it or can show me where I can find out?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  In your models you probably have an ICollection Or IQueryable which you are attempting to filter.  However IQueryables use Entityframework and need to translate your queries into SQL.  There are only set methods in which you can call on them

Comment: I am trying to create a filter. I want to pass some values via query string into my method. When the method gets the values, it takes the key and finds the matching property and then checks to see if the property value containers the query string value (so does a string comparison)

Comment: You're attempting to do dynamic filter?  You might want to look at OData, or Dynamic Linq

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675568/dynamic-filtering-using-linq) might help you

Comment: LINQ to Entities is based on how EF understands your LINQ query and is able to translate it into SQL. EF doesn't know among others, what GetType() method is and how to translate it.
You'd either need to write your own LINQ extensions using expression trees or follow one of the comments above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by using `System.Linq.Dynamic` as suggested and I was able to do this:

```
public class DataProvider<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IService<T> _service;
    public DataProvider(IService<T> service) => _service = service;

    public IQueryable<T> List(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var queryString = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
        var models = _service.List();
        foreach (var item in queryString)
        {
            var query = $"{ item.Key }.ToString().Contains(\"{ item.Value }\")";
            models = models.Where(query);
        }
        return models;
    }
}
```

Which allowed me to use Generics and fix my issue :)